# least upper bound of an infinite chain of values in a flat domain

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have an infinite list of the form

```
let l = [undefined,undefined] ++ [1,1..]
```

The key property here is that the list forms a chain in the flat domain Integer. Is there a way in haskell to find the least upper bound of the list l? My naive approach was the following:

```
Prelude> import Data.Lub
Prelude Data.Lub> foldr (\x y -> x `lub` y) undefined l
1
```

The problem is that a ghc process continues to use 100% of one of my CPU cores. I am using ghc version 7.10.3.

Comment: On integers, `lub` is `Data.Unamb.unamb`, whose precise semantics escapes me.

Comment: This looks like a bug in `unamb`. It may be overusing `mask_`, so that infinite computations are not being killed (I could reproduce this with a finite list containing infinite loops).

Answer (score 1):

After taking a closer look it is indeed a bug in unamb. [Here is a PR to fix it](https://github.com/conal/unamb/pull/1).